# Reading from XML file into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, openrowset

I am trying to read a physical xml file with below schema

```
    <Document>
<CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
<PmtInf>
  <DrctDbtTxInf>

    <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">1</InstdAmt>

   <DrctDbtTx>
      <MndtRltdInf>
        <MndtId>umr</MndtId>
        <DtOfSgntr>2020-04-07</DtOfSgntr>
      </MndtRltdInf>
    </DrctDbtTx>
   <Dbtr>
      <Nm>Akings</Nm>
    </Dbtr>

   <DbtrAcct>
      <Id>
        <IBAN>123456789132456789523</IBAN>
      </Id>
    </DbtrAcct>

  </DrctDbtTxInf>   
  </PmtInf>
      </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
    </Document>
```

By using the below query:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT @xml = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLELEMOS\MSSQL\Backup\test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x
SELECT
  t.c.query('InstdAmt').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
   t.c.query('Dbtr/Nm').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)')  
FROM @xml.nodes('*:Document/*:CstmrDrctDbtInitn/*:PmtInf/*:DrctDbtTxInf') t(c)
```

But I am getting blank results every time I run it, any idea of what could I be missing here?

Comment: The root node of the XML is `Dcoument` but you specified `Document` in the query. Change the XML or query to be consistent.

Comment: Actually I have changed it and still blanks

Comment: I ran your query after changing the element name to `Dcoument` and it returned "1 Akings".

Comment: Do you have any namespaces in your real XML?

Comment: yes there is namespaces, do I need to declare that somewhere else ?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have removed the namespaces from my file since they are not required and data is returning with the original query.

Comment: I don't see namespaces in your XML or code. Without removing the namespaces from the actual XML, you could specify them in the query along with the associated namespace prefixes.

Comment: @giantLincecum, from your answers here I take, that there is a default namespace (a simple `xmlns="someURI"` without any prefix. In this case your own query should work with `*:` wildcards everywhere (e.g. `t.c.query('InstdAmt')` => `t.c.query('*:InstdAmt')`)

Comment: @giantLincecum I just added some more to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check if reading the XML's content into your variable is working as expected. Assuming the XML is finally read successfully, this should work:

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Document>
  <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
    <PmtInf>
      <DrctDbtTxInf>
        <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">1</InstdAmt>
        <DrctDbtTx>
          <MndtRltdInf>
            <MndtId>umr</MndtId>
            <DtOfSgntr>2020-04-07</DtOfSgntr>
          </MndtRltdInf>
        </DrctDbtTx>
        <Dbtr>
          <Nm>Akings</Nm>
        </Dbtr>
        <DbtrAcct>
          <Id>
            <IBAN>123456789132456789523</IBAN>
          </Id>
        </DbtrAcct>
      </DrctDbtTxInf>
    </PmtInf>
  </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
</Document>';
```

--reading the values directly (if non-repeated)

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/Document/CstmrDrctDbtInitn/PmtInf/DrctDbtTxInf/InstdAmt/text())[1]','int') AS InstAmt
      ,@xml.value('(/Document/CstmrDrctDbtInitn/PmtInf/DrctDbtTxInf/Dbtr/Nm/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS InstAmt;
```

--reading - as you do it - with `.nodes()`

```
SELECT t.c.value('(InstdAmt/text())[1]','int') AS InstAmt
      ,t.c.value('(Dbtr/Nm/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS InstAmt
FROM @xml.nodes('/Document/CstmrDrctDbtInitn/PmtInf/DrctDbtTxInf') t(c);
```

Your own code is working too, actually...

The usage of the namespace wildcard (`*:`) and your blank results let me think, that the XML you are showing us is just a part of the whole thing. It might be enough (if the element `<Document>` does not appear in other places) to use a *deep search* with a doubled `//` at the beginning (=> start with `'//*:Document'`).

### UPDATE: If there is a (default) namespace

From your comments above I take, that there is a default namespace involved, just try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Document xmlns="someUri">   <!-- adding a default namespace here -->
  <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
    <PmtInf>
      <DrctDbtTxInf>
        <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">1</InstdAmt>
        <DrctDbtTx>
          <MndtRltdInf>
            <MndtId>umr</MndtId>
            <DtOfSgntr>2020-04-07</DtOfSgntr>
          </MndtRltdInf>
        </DrctDbtTx>
        <Dbtr>
          <Nm>Akings</Nm>
        </Dbtr>
        <DbtrAcct>
          <Id>
            <IBAN>123456789132456789523</IBAN>
          </Id>
        </DbtrAcct>
      </DrctDbtTxInf>
    </PmtInf>
  </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
</Document>';
```

--reading the values needs to declare the namespace(s)

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'someUri')
SELECT @xml.value('(/Document/CstmrDrctDbtInitn/PmtInf/DrctDbtTxInf/InstdAmt/text())[1]','int') AS InstAmt
      ,@xml.value('(/Document/CstmrDrctDbtInitn/PmtInf/DrctDbtTxInf/Dbtr/Nm/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS InstAmt;
```

Using the wildcard `*:` will work too, but makes you prone to errors, if there are name clashes in more complex sources.